# I have build my app in react native but i want reduce the size

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm using only text Image(3 images size may be total 1mb) components but My application is built in the 20 MB.
How I reduce the size minimum of 2-3 MB?

### Reducing the size of React Native App (Android)

This is what you have been waiting for,
I know.
Open up ***android/app/build.gradle***

> Set def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

this would enable Progaurd to compress the Java Bytecode.

This reduces the app size by a tad bit

> Set def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

Android devices support two major device artitectures armebi and x86. By default, RN build the native libraries for both these architectures into the same Apk.
Setting the last function creates two distinct Apk in the build folder. You have to upload both of this **Apk to Play Store and Google** would take care of distributing the app to the correct architectures.

Using this split generates version numbers for both Apk in the order of 104856 and such. This is auto-generated by the build to avoid version conflicts, so don’t freak out (I did).

This split reduced the **Apk size from around 7MB to 3.5MB** for arm and 5MB for x86 respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using non-expo way then there is a way to reduce app size.

**Short answer**

generate a bundle of your project

**Long anser**

> By default, the generated APK has the native code for both x86 and ARMv7a CPU architectures. This makes it easier to share APKs that run on almost all Android devices. However, this has the downside that there will be some unused native code on any device, leading to unnecessarily bigger APKs.

Just Split your app for different CPU structure

[Just follow that instruction](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#split-apks-by-abi-to-reduce-file-size)

If you are planning to upload your app on google-playstore, then just generate bundle and upload that bundle on play store. Google will do everything for you.

> Bundle will maybe  big in size but when your user see your app on play store it would have less size depending on their CPU structure

Answer (score 2):

The built React Native app contains your images of course, but all the React Native stuff necessary to the app itself, with a lot of modules.

Currently it's not really possible to have a much smaller size React Native than ~ 9mb.

**EDIT** : @jsRook confirms it's possible to have a ~9mb app.

Comment: I had an app in play store with the size of  only 9mb made from react native